# How to add date automatically based on the other column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, dataset

I am pretty new to Datetime and pandas. So, I created a code that generates new data(extra rows) to a column, whereas my index is the date. Now depending on the new rows which got created in a column, the date also should get automatically added depending on the above. Is there any way to do it?

My input:

```
df=
            column1
2020-12-22    1
2020-12-23    2
2020-12-24    3
```

After the code which I run to gain more data in column1, the output is as follows:

```
            column1
2020-12-22    1
2020-12-23    2
2020-12-24    3
0             4
1             5
3             6
4             7
```

Expected Output:

```
    column1
2020-12-22    1
2020-12-23    2
2020-12-24    3
2020-12-25    4
2020-12-26    5
2020-12-27    6
2020-12-28    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `DatetimeIndex` by maximal datetime from original `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
max1 = df.index.max()
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index + 1, origin=max1, unit='D')
```

Comment: I got a error TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: @sirisha - `df1` has no `DatetimeIndex`, it has `RangeIndex (0,1,2,3)`

Comment: @sirisha - and `df` has `DatetimeIndex`